# How to check if a Java 8 Stream is empty?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How can I check if a `Stream` is empty and throw an exception if it's not, as a non-terminal operation?

Basically, I'm looking for something equivalent to the code below, but without materializing the stream in-between. In particular, the check should not occur before the stream is actually consumed by a terminal operation.

```
public Stream<Thing> getFilteredThings() {
    Stream<Thing> stream = getThings().stream()
                .filter(Thing::isFoo)
                .filter(Thing::isBar);
    return nonEmptyStream(stream, () -> {
        throw new RuntimeException("No foo bar things available")   
    });
}

private static <T> Stream<T> nonEmptyStream(Stream<T> stream, Supplier<T> defaultValue) {
    List<T> list = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
    if (list.isEmpty()) list.add(defaultValue.get());
    return list.stream();
}
```

Comment: You can't have your cake and eat it too--and quite literally so, in this context. You have to *consume* the stream to find out if it's empty. That's the point of Stream's semantics (laziness).

Comment: It will be consumed eventually, at this point the check should occur

Comment: To check that the stream is not empty you have to attempt to consume at least one element. At that point the stream has lost its "virginity" and cannot be consumed again from the start.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik just because it's lazy doesn't mean it couldn't in principle buffer and reemit the element that was peeked on. See vavr stream

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you can live with limited parallel capablilities, the following solution will work:

```
private static <T> Stream<T> nonEmptyStream(
    Stream<T> stream, Supplier<RuntimeException> e) {

    Spliterator<T> it=stream.spliterator();
    return StreamSupport.stream(new Spliterator<T>() {
        boolean seen;
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
            boolean r=it.tryAdvance(action);
            if(!seen && !r) throw e.get();
            seen=true;
            return r;
        }
        public Spliterator<T> trySplit() { return null; }
        public long estimateSize() { return it.estimateSize(); }
        public int characteristics() { return it.characteristics(); }
    }, false);
}
```

Here is some example code using it:

```
List<String> l=Arrays.asList("hello", "world");
nonEmptyStream(l.stream(), ()->new RuntimeException("No strings available"))
  .forEach(System.out::println);
nonEmptyStream(l.stream().filter(s->s.startsWith("x")),
               ()->new RuntimeException("No strings available"))
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The problem with (efficient) parallel execution is that supporting splitting of the `Spliterator` requires a thread-safe way to notice whether either of the fragments has seen any value in a thread-safe manner. Then the last of the fragments executing `tryAdvance` has to realize that it is the last one (and it also couldn’t advance) to throw the appropriate exception. So I didn’t add support for splitting here.

Answer (score 109):

This may be sufficient in many cases

```
stream.findAny().isPresent()
```

Comment: Simple and crisp solution.  This code will consume the stream, so we will have to make another stream if we want to iterate when it is not empty.

Comment: If you happen to have a last `filter()` operation before needing to `count()`. you can replace the sequence `...filter(expr.findAny().isPresent());` by `...anyMatch(expr)`

Comment: Nice idea, @juanmf. In the simple case without filter one may even do `stream.anyMatch(true)` if one doesn’t find it too cryptic.

Answer (score 44):

The other answers and comments are correct in that to examine the contents of a stream, one must add a terminal operation, thereby "consuming" the stream. However, one can do this and turn the result back into a stream, without buffering up the entire contents of the stream. Here are a couple examples:

```
static <T> Stream<T> throwIfEmpty(Stream<T> stream) {
    Iterator<T> iterator = stream.iterator();
    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, 0), false);
    } else {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("empty stream");
    }
}

static <T> Stream<T> defaultIfEmpty(Stream<T> stream, Supplier<T> supplier) {
    Iterator<T> iterator = stream.iterator();
    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, 0), false);
    } else {
        return Stream.of(supplier.get());
    }
}
```

Basically turn the stream into an `Iterator` in order to call `hasNext()` on it, and if true, turn the `Iterator` back into a `Stream`. This is inefficient in that all subsequent operations on the stream will go through the Iterator's `hasNext()` and `next()` methods, which also implies that the stream is effectively processed sequentially (even if it's later turned parallel). However, this does allow you to test the stream without buffering up all of its elements.

There is probably a way to do this using a `Spliterator` instead of an `Iterator`. This potentially allows the returned stream to have the same characteristics as the input stream, including running in parallel.

Comment: I don’t think that there is a maintainable solution that would support efficient parallel processing as it’s hard to support splitting, however having `estimatedSize` and `characteristics` might even improve single-threaded performance. It just happened that I wrote the `Spliterator` solution while you were posting the `Iterator` solution…

Comment: You can ask the stream for a Spliterator, call tryAdvance(lambda) where your lambda captures anything passed to it, and then return a Spliterator that delegates almost everything to the underlying Spliterator, except that it glues the first element back onto the first chunk (and fixes up the result of estimateSize).

Comment: @BrianGoetz Yes, that was my thought, I just haven't yet bothered to go through the leg work of handling all those details.

Comment: @Brian Goetz: That’s what I meant with “too complicated”. Calling `tryAdvance` before the `Stream` does it turns the lazy nature of the `Stream` into a “partially lazy” stream. It also implies that searching for the first element is not a parallel operation anymore as you have to split first and do `tryAdvance` on the split parts concurrently to do a real parallel operation, as far as I understood. If the sole terminal operation is `findAny` or similar that would destroy the entire `parallel()` request.

Comment: So for full parallel support you must not call `tryAdvance` before the stream does and have to wrap every split part into a proxy and gather the “hasAny” information of all concurrent operations on your own and ensure that the last concurrent operation throws the desired exception if the stream was empty. Lots of stuff…

Comment: Nice. In my case it was fine to process the elements of the `Iterator` (in a `do`-`while`) without converting back to `Stream`  in the non-empty case.

Answer (score 20):

You must perform a terminal operation on the Stream in order for any of the filters to be applied. Therefore you can't know if it will be empty until you consume it.

Best you can do is terminate the Stream with a `findAny()` terminal operation, which will stop when it finds any element, but if there are none, it will have to iterate over all the input list to find that out.

This would only help you if the input list has many elements, and one of the first few passes the filters, since only a small subset of the list would have to be consumed before you know the Stream is not empty.

Of course you'll still have to create a new Stream in order to produce the output list.

Comment: There's `anyMatch(alwaysTrue())`, I think that's the closest to `hasAny`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Just checked the reference - what I had in mind was findAny(), though anyMatch() would also work.

Comment: `anyMatch(alwaysTrue())` perfectly matches the intended semantics of your `hasAny`, giving you a `boolean` instead of `Optional<T>`---but we're splitting hairs here :)

Comment: Note `alwaysTrue` is a Guava predicate.

Comment: `anyMatch(e -> true)` then.

Answer (score 9):

I think should be enough to map a boolean

In code this is:

```
boolean isEmpty = anyCollection.stream()
    .filter(p -> someFilter(p)) // Add my filter
    .map(p -> Boolean.TRUE) // For each element after filter, map to a TRUE
    .findAny() // Get any TRUE
    .orElse(Boolean.FALSE); // If there is no match return false
```

Comment: If this is all you need, kenglxn's answer is better.

Comment: its useless, it duplicates Collection.isEmpty()

Comment: @Krzysiek it's not useless if you need to filter the collection. However, I do agree with Dominykas on that kenglxn's answer is better

Comment: It is because it also duplicates `Stream.anyMatch()`

Answer (score 5):

Following Stuart's idea, this could be done with a `Spliterator` like this:

```
static <T> Stream<T> defaultIfEmpty(Stream<T> stream, Stream<T> defaultStream) {
    final Spliterator<T> spliterator = stream.spliterator();
    final AtomicReference<T> reference = new AtomicReference<>();
    if (spliterator.tryAdvance(reference::set)) {
        return Stream.concat(Stream.of(reference.get()), StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, stream.isParallel()));
    } else {
        return defaultStream;
    }
}
```

I think this works with parallel Streams as the `stream.spliterator()` operation will terminate the stream, and then rebuild it as required

In my use-case I needed a default `Stream` rather than a default value. that's quite easy to change if this is not what you need

Comment: I can't figure out whether this would significantly impact performance with parallel streams. Should probably test it if this is a requirement

Comment: Sorry didn't realise that @Holger also had a solution with `Spliterator` I wonder how the two compare.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use:

```
stream.count()>0
```

Comment: This only works, if you do not have to process the stream. When you want to process the elements, it does not work, because after count()  the stream is consumed. count is a terminal operation.

Comment: This also unnecessarily consumes and counts the __whole__ stream, where a "lazy" (short-circuiting) `.findAny()` would only process a single item and finish.

Comment: How this is better than `Optional.isPresent()` ? This is much worse than the other solutions!

Answer (score 0):

The best simple solution I could find that does not consume the stream or convert to iterators is:

```
public Stream<Thing> getFilteredThings() {
    AtomicBoolean found = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    Stream<Thing> stream = getThings().stream()
        .filter(Thing::isFoo)
        .filter(Thing::isBar)
        .forEach(x -> {
             found.set(true);
             // do useful things
         })
    ;
    if (!found.get()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("No foo bar things available");
    }
}
```

Feel free to suggest improvements..