# Unsplittable Spliterators

Tags: java, java-8, spliterator

I'm trying to understand how `Spliterator` works, and how spliterators are designed.  I recognize that `trySplit()` is likely one of the more important methods of `Spliterator`, but when I see some third-party `Spliterator` implementations, sometimes I see that their spliterators return null for `trySplit()` unconditionally.

The questions:

1. Is there a difference between an ordinary iterator and a `Spliterator` that returns null unconditionally? It seems like such a spliterator defeats the point of, well, splitting.
2. Of course, there are legitimate use cases of spliterators that conditionally return null on `trySplit()`, but is there a legitimate use case of a spliterator that unconditionally returns null?

Comment: Right.  The question is regarding implementations of `trySplit()` that is literally `return null`.

Answer (score 6):

While the main advantage of Spliterator over Iterator is, as you said, its trySplit() method which allows it to be parallelized, there are other significant advantages:

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html
>
> The Spliterator API was designed to support efficient parallel traversal in addition to sequential traversal, by supporting decomposition as well as single-element iteration. **In addition, the protocol for accessing elements via a Spliterator is designed to impose smaller per-element overhead than Iterator, and to avoid the inherent race involved in having separate methods for hasNext() and next().**

Furthermore, Spliterators can be directly converted to Streams using [StreamSupport.stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html#stream-java.util.Spliterator-boolean-) to make use of Java8's streams.

Comment: I wouldn’t call that a *minor* advantage. I have implemented a lot of `Iterator`s and from that, I can say that splitting the traverse logic into two methods complicates most of them. There are lots of existing methods having a “get next item or `null`/special value on end” logic. With such a back-end method, an iterator’s `hasNext` method has to remember the returned value for the next `next` call and both methods have to track whether they have been called already. In contrast, a `tryAdvance` method is trivial to implement.

Comment: @Holger Great; so why are the spliterators around the JDK implemented through Iterator?? Now I saw new code for JDK 9, stream support in Matcher, again they use Iterator then wrap into Spliterator.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: a typical case of “I don’t use what I don’t know” combined with “once written, almost never changed”. There is a [bug report regarding `String.chars()`](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8071477) and thus, this implementation has been changed in Java 9. There is a related bug report for [`Files.lines`](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8072773) with the neat comment “This was noted when it was originally implemented too, the decision at the time was to re-visit it at a later time”. So you have to file bug reports for each place to force revision of the code.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik The premise of your question is incorrect. Most spliterators in the JDK -- and certainly all the most important ones -- are implemented directly.  See ArrayList, TreeSet, Arrays.stream, etc.

Comment: Edited "minor" -> "significant" to reflect reality :)   Spliterator is a better iterator in most dimensions: less racy, more performant, more information-preserving.  Downside is that they're more work to implement.

Comment: @BrianGoetz My premise was not "all spliterators are implemented through Iterator". But what is harder about extending `AbstractSpliterator` than implementing `Iterator`? All you need to override is a single method.

Answer (score 4):

One of the purposes of a `Spliterator` is to be able to split, but that's not the only purpose. The other main purpose is as a support class for creating your own `Stream` source. One way to create a Stream source is to implement your own Spliterator and pass it to [`StreamSupport.stream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html#stream-java.util.Spliterator-boolean-). The simplest thing to do is often to write a Spliterator that can't split. Doing so forces the stream to execute sequentially, but that might be acceptable for whatever you're trying to do.

There are other cases where writing a non-splittable Spliterator makes sense. For example, in OpenJDK, there are implementations such as [`EmptySpliterator`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/jdk8-b132/src/share/classes/java/util/Spliterators.java#l836) that contain no elements. Of course it can't be split. A similar case is a [singleton spliterator](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/43cb25339b55/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java#l4756) that contains exactly one element. It can't be split either. Both implementations return `null` unconditionally from `trySplit`.

Another case is where writing a non-splittable Spliterator is easy and effective, and the amount of code necessary to implement a splittable one is prohibitive. (At least, not worth the effort of writing one into a Stack Overflow answer.) For example, see the example Spliterator from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649062/how-to-check-if-a-java-8-stream-is-empty/26659678#26659678). The case here is that the Spliterator implementation wants to wrap another Spliterator and do something special, in this case check to see if it's not empty. Otherwise it just delegates everything to the wrapped Spliterator. Doing this with a non-splittable Spliterator is pretty easy.

Notice that there's discussion in that answer, the comment on that answer, in [my answer to the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649062/how-to-check-if-a-java-8-stream-is-empty/26659413#26659413), and the comment thread on my answer, about how one would make a splittable (i.e., parallel-ready) Spliterator. But nobody actually wrote out the code to do the splitting. :-) Depending upon how much laziness you want to preserve from the original stream, and how much parallel efficiency you want, writing a splittable Spliterator can get pretty complicated.

In my estimation it's somewhat easier to do this sort of stuff by writing an Iterator instead of a Spliterator (as in my answer noted above). It turns out that `Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize` can provide a limited amount of parallelism, even from an Iterator, which is apparently a purely sequential construct. It does so within [`IteratorSpliterator`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/jdk8-b132/src/share/classes/java/util/Spliterators.java#l1684), which pulls multiple elements from the Iterator and processes them in batches. Unfortunately the batch size is hardcoded, but at least this gives the opportunity for processing elements pulled from an Iterator in parallel in certain cases.

Comment: I don’t agree about the “easier … writing an Iterator” point. I have written too many `Iterator`s to see it that way. When I first saw the `tryAdvance` method, I was so excited, I didn’t care about all these other features. I converted all `Iterator`s in my code and don’t regret it. I was very surprised when I noticed how many new Java 8 methods implement the more complicated `Iterator`s where `Spliterator`s are required. It seems that this is all just about what programmers are used to. Granted, getting a single item without storing it into a data structure doesn’t work with `Spliterator`s…

Comment: To qualify @Holger's statement, it is definitely harder to meet the full contract of `Spliterator` from scratch; however starting out from `AbstractSpliterator` it's usually a breeze, and simpler than `Iterator`.

Comment: @Holger I think "easier" is mostly a matter of taste, though I don't actually disagree with anything you say. I do note, as did you, that many stream sources in the JDK, including the new [`Matcher.results`](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8071479) API, are implemented using an Iterator and `spliteratorUnknownSize()`. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 2):

There are more advantages than just splitting support:

- The iteration logic is contained in a single `tryAdvance` method rather than being spread over two methods like `hasNext`, `next`. Splitting the logic over two methods complicates a lot of `Iterator` implementations, as it often implies that the `hasNext` method has to perform an actual query attempt that might yield a value which then has to be remembered for the follow-up `next` call. And the fact that this query has been made must be remembered as well, either explicit or implicitly.

  It would be easier if there was a guaranty that `hasNext`/`next` are always called in the typical alternating fashion, however, there is no such guaranty.

  One example is `BufferedReader.readLine()` which has a simple `tryAdvance` logic. A wrapping `Iterator` has to call that method within the `hasNext` implementation and remember the line for the `next` call. (Ironically, the current `BufferedReader.stream()` implementation *does* implement such a complicated `Iterator` that will be wrapped into a `Spliterator` instead of implementing the much simpler `Spliterator` directly. It seems that the “I’m not familiar with that” problem should not be underestimated)
- `estimateSize()`; a `Spliterator` may return an estimate (or even an exact number) of the remaining items that can be used to pre-allocate resources. This can raise efficiency.
- `characteristics()`; `Spliterator`s can provide additional information about their content or behavior. Besides telling whether the estimated size is an exact size, you can learn whether you may see `null` values, whether there is a defined encounter order or all values are distinct. A particular algorithm may take advantage of this. Clearly, the `Stream` API is a buildup of such algorithms that *may* take advantage so when planning to create (or support creation of) streams and have a choice, implementing a `Spliterator` telling as much meta-information as possible is preferred to implementing an `Iterator` that will be wrapped later.