# How to get ordered stream from a list in reverse order in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is there a sane way to get an ordered stream from a list (array list specifically, but it shouldn't matter) that streams elements in reverse of how they are in the original list?

I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve buffering data in anything (collector, another list, array, etc, because they copy the container which is wasteful), or uses `Collections.reverse` (because it modifies the list).

So far, the cleanest ways that I see here is to implement my own version of `Spliterator` that's `ORDERED` and advances through the list in reverse, or implement an `Iterator` that iterates in reverse, and use `Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator,ORDERED)` on it.

Note this question is different from [Java 8 stream reverse order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010109/java-8-stream-reverse-order) : that other question asks on how to reverse a stream (which is impossible in general case), and answers offer to reverse the source somehow (which I don't want to do), and then stream that reversed source. The cost of reversing the source is O(N), and I want to avoid it at all if possible.

Comment: This article covers several possibilities: http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/028-reverse-order-stream-elements-java8/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**NOTE:** If you have an `ArrayList` or other list that allows random-access retrieval by index (`get(i)`) then [Holger's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29409584/1441122) is preferable. The approach below is only necessary if you have a data structure that allows reverse traversal but not indexed access.

---

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a really simple (i.e., a one-liner) way to do this. But getting a reversed stream using `AbstractSpliterator` isn't too difficult, given that `List` already has the ability to iterate in reverse. Here's a utility method to do that:

```
static <T> Stream<T> reversedStream(List<? extends T> input) {
    ListIterator<? extends T> li = input.listIterator(input.size());
    return StreamSupport.stream(
        new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<T>(input.size(), Spliterator.ORDERED) {
            @Override public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
                if (li.hasPrevious()) {
                    action.accept(li.previous());
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        },
        false);
}
```

(I suppose the Spliterator could be `SIZED`, but that's mostly pointless because this is an [unsplittable spliterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28869111/unsplittable-spliterators).)

As it stands, this can afford a limited degree of parallelism, as `AbstractSpliterator` will call `tryAdvance` multiple times and batch up work to hand off to fork-join tasks. But it's not as efficient as being able to split.

If parallel efficiency is a great concern, one could write a spliterator that can actually split, where the splits are traversed in reverse order.

Comment: So, using `AbstractSpliterator` is somehow better than `IteratorSpliterator`?

Comment: I don’t think that `SIZED` is pointless. `SUBSIZED` would be pointless though.

Comment: @PawelVeselov I think that `AbstractSpliterator` is a bit easier than writing your own iterator. But if you already have an iterator, then using `Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, ...)` -- which uses `IteratorSpliterator` underneath -- is certainly easier to code.

Comment: @Holger Yes, `SIZED` might allow the stream to do better buffering, but I'm not sure. Well, in JDK 9 it would allow `count()` to short-circuit.

Comment: @StuartMarks I was more wondering about any implementation execution advantages. The only disadvantage of `AbstractIterator` that I see that its `trySplit()` method costs one more object creation (`HoldingConsumer`). (long time no see, btw:) )

Comment: @PawelVeselov (I think you mean `AbstractSpliterator`?) There are some tradeoffs. The `IteratorSpliterator` doesn't need a `HoldingConsumer` but it does require an extra method call (hasNext+next) for each element. But that might be offset by the `Consumer.accept` call... hmmm. Well I think the only real way to find out is to measure. (And yes, it's been a while!) :-)

Answer (score 23):

If your `List` is a random access list, you may simply use

```
int num=list.size()-1;
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, num).mapToObj(i->list.get(num-i))
```

to create a `Stream` which has the characteristics `ORDERED | SIZED | SUBSIZED` and offers full splitting support.

For a non-random access list like `LinkedList` it would be a performance disaster, however, who uses `LinkedList` anyway?

You may also check via `list instanceof`[`RandomAccess`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html) first…

Comment: Heh, I should have thought of this first. +1. I guess I was too enamored with the idea of writing a reversing spliterator.

Comment: Or `IntStream.rangeClosed(1, list.size()).mapToObj(i -> list.get(list.size() - i))`.

Answer (score 6):

Starting with Java 21, the [`reversed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#reversed()) method can be used to return a reversed view on the list, which can then be streamed over:

```java
Stream<Object> reversedStream = list.reversed().stream();
```

As requested, this doesn't buffer or copy the data, as this is merely a reversed view of the original list.

Answer (score 5):

Google's Guava library provides a reverse view of a list ([`Lists#reverse(List)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#reverse-java.util.List-)). There's a [`ReverseListIterator`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/iterators/ReverseListIterator.html) in the Apache Commons Collection library, too.

Answer (score 5):

I found this solution quite recently.

```
public <T> Stream<T> toReverseStream(List<T> list) {
    ListIterator<T> listIterator = list.listIterator(list.size());
    return Stream.generate(listIterator::previous)
            .limit(list.size());
}
```

Comment: Not a good idea. `Stream.generate(…)` creates an *unordered* stream. Further, a Stream stage should not rely on the effect of a subsequent stage. In other words, there is no guaranty that the supplier is only evaluated as often as specified by the limit. It may happen to do the desired thing in sequential contexts but may fail with parallel execution in practice. But on the formal level, it’s wrong in either case.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to like @teppic's answer of using a third-party library to do this.  However, it's an interesting exercise to try to come up with a solution using only the Java 8 APIs.  Delegating to a `ListIterator` is the cleanest thing I could come up with, but it's not really much cleaner than implementing your own `Iterator` from scratch.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    List<String> l = Arrays.asList("first", "second", "third");

    StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliterator(revit(l), l.size(), 0), false)
                 .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
}

private static final <T> Iterator<T> revit(List<T> l){
    ListIterator<T> li = l.listIterator(l.size());

    return new Iterator<T>(){
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext(){
            return li.hasPrevious();
        }

        @Override
        public T next(){
            return li.previous();
        }
    };
}
```