# Throw exception if filter returns a list of size 0

Tags: java, java-stream

In the following code:

```
myList.stream()
    .filter(item -> someMethod(item))
    .map(item -> doSomething(item))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How can I throw a `RuntimeException` if the result of the filter is a list of size 0 (i.e. no item passes the filter)?

Comment: Why no just after collecting, check if the list is empty and throw the RuntimeException?

Comment: The result is being returned. So for the purpose of readability and consistency with the rest of the code, I'd like to check it somewhere within the stream.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [collectingAndThen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-):

```
    myList.stream()
            .filter(item -> someMethod(item))
            .map(item -> doSomething(item))
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), result -> {
                if (result.isEmpty()) throw new RuntimeException("Empty!!");
                return result;
            }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no straight forward way of [How to check if a Java 8 Stream is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649062/how-to-check-if-a-java-8-stream-is-empty), a much preferrable code would be :

```
List<SomeObject> output = myList.stream()
        .filter(item -> someMethod(item))
        .map(item -> doSomething(item))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
if (!myList.isEmpty() && output.isEmpty()) {
    throw new RuntimeException("your message");
}
```

---

Another alternative to this could be using `noneMatch`, to validate before the execution such as:

```
if (myList.stream().noneMatch(item -> someMethod(item))) {
    throw new RuntimeException("your message");
}
```